# erlang server on port 6657?

Tags: bash, erlang, erlang-shell, erlang-ports

**Problem :** 
I am trying to run the noshell command as following and keep alive the server on port 6657, but seems that does not work.

**run_server.sh**

```
erl -make
erl -pa ebin/ -noshell -s server main 6657 -s init stop
```

**Erlang module function**

```
main(Port) ->
    controller:start(),
```

FYI, on erlang prompt I can execute command - `server:main(6667)` 
that works fine.

Can you please suggest me what I need to change in that command ?

Thanks you !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the module name right (you say `server` in the first snippet and `chat_server` later), the problem most likely is that `-s module function arg1 [...]` sends the arguments as a list of atoms, while your code requires a single integer (as you said `server:main(6657)` works). You can use `-eval` instead of `-s`:

```
erl -pa ebin/ -noshell -eval "server:main(6657)" -s init stop
```

```
$ cat a.erl
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

main(Port) ->
  io:format("~p~n", [Port]).
$ erlc a.erl
$ erl -noshell -pa . -s a main 6657 -s init stop
['6657']
$ erl -noshell -pa . -eval 'a:main(6657)' -s init stop
6657
```

Comment: http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html
`erl -pa ebin/ -noshell -run "server:main(6657)" -s init stop` will crash

**-run Mod [Func [Arg1, Arg2, ...]] (init flag)**

Comment: Oops, I made a typo there. That should be `-eval`, not `-run`. Please see edit.

Comment: I can execute this command ```erl -pa ebin/ -noshell -eval "server:main(6657)" -s init stop```without crash , but the server is not running all the time. How I can keep running the server on port 6656 ? Thanks @Dogbert and @kevin

Comment: @Dogbert I have modified the question with correct module name

Comment: @J4cK I believe you're looking for `-detached` and no `-s init stop`: `erl -pa ebin/ -noshell -detached -eval "server:main(6657)"`, BUT, unless this is just for playing around, you should use something like systemd/upstart in production so that the server is properly restarted if/when it crashes.